# jQuery post return multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This multidimensional array is returned to jQuery

```
    foreach($results as $result) {
                $note_id = $result->ID;
                $return_array[$note_id]['status_type'] = $result->status_type;
                $return_array[$note_id]['note'] = $result->notes;
                $return_array[$note_id]['username'] = $result->username;
                $date_time = $result->updated;
                    $timestamp = strtotime($date_time);

                $day_submitted =  date("F jS Y", $timestamp);
                $time_submitted = date("H:i", $timestamp);

                $return_array[$note_id]['date_time'] = "$day_submitted<br>$time_submitted";

            }

echo json_encode($return_array);
```

The problem is i can't access the values.. here is my attempt

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    load_btn.hide();

    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
        alert(response[index].status_type);
    });
});
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't `parse` the string to `JSON`.

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

Add this as first statement in `post` callback.

Comment: jQuery doesn't intelligently guess the data format? :o

Comment: @Huey No, you need to provide it

Comment: But from the [documentation for jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), the default datatype if unspecified is * Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html)*. Sorry, but just curious about this.

Comment: @Huey That is the `data type` to POST data, not for `response` data